# Modify width of main text block in tufte-handout

Tags: tufte, width

Is it possible to increase the size of the main text in the `tufte-handout` class to 80% of the paper width?

Comment: you can change it using the geometry package, but please create a MWE so people do not waste too much time trying out a solution for you.

Comment: I believe that, for those who actually *like* it, the whole point of tufte-handout is the wide margins...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can issue `\geometry{textwidth=.8\paperwidth}` in the preamble to recompute the typing area, but then marginalia would be set in a really tight space.

Comment: this actually forces the running header off the right hand pages.

Comment: This solution works for ```\geometry{textwidth=.3\paperwidth}``` by reducing the text width, but it didn't work for ```\geometry{textwidth=.5\paperwidth}```, which seemed no effect. But the reduced horizontal space, I want to give to the margin, but it does not achieve that. I need a separate solution for that.